# To sum data for until a certain date

Tags: excel

```
            01-Mar     02-Mar   03-Mar
Actual        1          1        1
Allocation    3          0        2
Variance      2         -1        1
```

Assume the date today is 3rd March

How to sum the value of Actual until 2nd March only

Answer (score 1):

use SUMIF:

```
=SUMIF($E$1:$G$1,"<2014-03-03",E2:G2) //range, criteria, sum range
```

if you want to sum values less than today, you can modify the formula as:

```
=SUMIF($E$1:$G$1,"<"&today()-1,E2:G2) //this will evaluate the criteria as dates till yesterday
```

Here's the sample output.

[image]

**Update**

If you're using a date value from cell to compare as criteria, make sure that it's a **Date** value otherwise it not give you desired output. See here in the formula bar:

[image]

The value in cell is "3-Mar" but is a date value as it shows in formula bar.

In case if it's a text value and you want to compare as date, use TEXT function to convert and then compare:

You can see here in below picture where I've a string value in cell K1 and in the next picture how i used TEXT function to convert and use it as a Date value:

**Picture1**
[image]

**Picture2**
[image]

HTH !

Comment: hi sunny thanks for the formula.the first formula works but the formula that evaluate criteria until a specific date does not really work. im not sure if im doing the correct way...do we need to format the date

Comment: perhaps you've a string instead of date value in cell. please check the updated answer.